# Access Child Route Parameter from Parent Component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

This code works, but will not update when the route changes, how to accomplish? 
Code from parent component:

```
  ......
  searchType : string;
  searchTypeSubscription : Subscription;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTypeSubscription = this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.searchType = params.get("type")
    })
      console.log(this.searchType);
  }
  .......
```

Routes are defined like so:

```
const ParentRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'search/:type', component: ChildSearchComponent 
      },
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] on codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can try and help you

Comment: I've been unable to solve this from the parent component. I inject the parent into the child and call a method from there. Seems that active route on the child is the only way to get updates on the param map. Anyone else know a better way?